# TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X' ;

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having a problem with `TypeError` as following :

**code**

```
X=data.iloc[:,:-1].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
```

**error log**

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-16-46e01eb51381> in <module>()
 ----> 1 X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

Comment: Based on the documentation for StandardScaler and its fit_transform function, what's unclear about the error?

Comment: these line got "X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)"  ERROR

Comment: Glad you figured it out, however based on your answer below, this is a simple typo, so is worthy of closing this post based on what is off topic mentioned at [help]

Comment: I know that's my mistake, I am new in @stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
sc = StandardScaler
```

I need to use StandardScaler class

```
sc = StanderdScaler()
```